# graph representation of a Boolean function

Tags: graphs, combinatorics, boolean-algebra

I'm trying to classify a certain family of Boolean functions, and need to represent the function as a graph. Is there any well-known graph representation for a Boolean function that captures the information that it is Boolean?

I'm presently using the variables as vertices with an edge between two if they are present in the same monomial. This does not take into account that the function is Boolean.
I thought of 2-colorings of the vertices of a hypercube, but that does not really put any restriction on the graph. For my problem, I would need to use some property of the graph that results from the function being Boolean. Can someone provide some ideas to do this?

Comment: Your question is extremely vague. Perhaps you would like to share the actual problem you are interested in?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I am trying to classify all flat and homogeneous Boolean functions (i.e. every monomial has the same degree and the function has a flat Fourier spectrum). I have an idea to do this via representing the function as a graph, since I see that product and composition of two Boolean functions has nice interpretations in graph theory (using join of graphs). I wish to take an arbitrary such Boolean function, look at a graph representation and deduce properties of the graph. But I cant think of any such graph representation that uses the fact that the function is Boolean.

Comment: What do you mean by *flat Fourier spectrum*?

Comment: By flat spectrum I mean all the Fourier coefficients have the same magnitude.

Comment: The degree 2 case is known. For larger degrees, your graph loses a lot of information. It might be better to construct a hypergraph instead, perhaps even coloring the hyperedges according to sign.

Comment: Please don't put clarifications in the comments.  Instead, please [edit] the question to incorporate all relevant information, then flag comments as 'no longer needed'. Make the question read well for someone who encounters it for the first time.  We don't want people to have to read the comments to understand what is being asked.

Comment: @yuvalfilmus can you link me to a work that covers the degree 2 case?

Comment: I'm not sure it appears in any published work. Nisan and Szegedy showed that degree 2 Boolean functions depend on at most 4 coordinates, which is small enough to enable a complete classification by brute force search (or even by hand).

Comment: @YuvalFilmus thanks a lot. Just one last request - can you help me find the paper where Nisan and Szegedy show a degree 2 Boolean function depending on atmost 4 coordinates?

Comment: This is proved in Nisan and Szegedy, [On the degree of Boolean functions as real polynomials](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01263419.pdf).